# Entry widget - how to write in it without first clicking the entry box

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to know how to:

Write something into the `Tkinter` entry box *without first clicking into it* - so that simply writing in keyboard automatically writes the text into the entry box.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are  you familiar with the concept of _focus_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.focus_force()`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

entry = Entry(root)

entry.pack()

entry.focus_force()
```